# No AJAX request

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, call

i can't see any AJAX request to the webservice.php ( i use firebug), but i don't know why!

HTML Code:

```
<form id="form_login" name="form_login" method="POST">

E-Mail: <input type="text" size="30" name="email" id="email"></br>
Passwort: <input type="text" size="30" name="password" id="password"></br>
DeviceID: <input type="text" size="30" name="deviceid" id="deviceid"></br>

<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit_login" />
```

JS Code:

```
$(function () {
    $('form_login').on('submit_login', function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "webservice.php?method=CheckUserLogin",
            data: $('form_login').serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

It doesn't work, but i really don't know why...

Comment: "doesn't work" doesn't really help us understand the problem, did you submit the form, where are you looking for this ajax request, you know the methods are different, the form has POST, the ajax GET etc.

Comment: What is error message ?

Comment: And ID's start with `#`

Comment: a mistake, should be `$('#form_login')` instead of `$('form_login')`

Comment: I think is because the event triggered is `submit` try with `.on('submit',`

Comment: okay, sorry, on the firebug plug-in, there will be no AJAX request send. Yes, but that's not the problem, or?

Comment: Also your method in form is `POST` and you are passing the data by `GET` in `JS`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form_login').on('submit_login', function (e) {
```

should be:

```
$('#form_login').on('someevent','[name="submit_login"]', function (e) {
```

and

```
data: $('form_login').serialize(),
```

should be:

```
data: $('#form_login').serialize(),
```

`#` is used to select the element with id, and `[]` is used to select element with attribute.

Comment: that's not the problem, where i can see an error? i see nothing in the firebug plugin! :/

Comment: $(function () {
 $('#form_login').on('[name="submit_login"]', function (e) {
  alert("test");

and i don't get the alert! :/

Comment: Try downloading fiddler, it'll give you more insight on the requests http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: werbung/login.php?email=&password=&deviceid=&submit_login=Login

is see this in the fiddler, i think there is somethong wrong, but i don't know what

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form_login').on('submit_login', function (e) {
```

should be:

```
$('form_login').on('submit', function (e) {
```

because submit_login is not a valid parameter!